# Configuration management on yocto

Tags: configuration, web-config, yocto

I want to use web management on freescale board,
what is the best way to do that?
I try to use luci but I don’t use Openwrt so it became difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what's your requirement?

If you want a web-based configuration interface, that already has an available recipe, I think [webmin](http://cgit.openembedded.org/cgit.cgi/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-webserver/recipes-webadmin/webmin/) is the only one I found. I've used that one in a couple of projects.

Otherwise, it shouldn't be any problem to add a recipe for whatever web-based configuration system you prefer. (There's a few I'd prefer, but those tend to be GPLv3, which I couldn't use in those projects).

Building luci, isn't that hard either.